# Calculating point on circle given angle and distance traveled without calculating radius

Tags: circles

I want to calculate the X,Y coordinates of a point on a circle given only the distance and angle traveled, **without calculating the radius as an intermediate step**.

My starting point (0,0) is at the top of the circle. I know how far I have traveled around the circumference, and I know the angle I have subtended.

Because the angle could be very small or zero and this has to be performed in 32bit floating point arithmetic I want to avoid having to calculate the radius or location of the center of the circle (which could be infinite or very, very large)

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: if $r$ is the radius and angles, measured w.r.t. the vertical axis,  are in radians, the distance travelled is $d=r\theta$.

On the other hand, $x=r\cos\bigl(\frac\pi2+\theta\bigr)=-r\sin\theta\:$ and $\:y=r\sin\bigl(\frac\pi2+\theta\bigr)-r =r(\cos\theta -1) $, so that
\begin{cases}
x=-\dfrac{d\sin \theta}\theta,\\[1ex]
y=\dfrac{d(\cos\theta-1)}\theta.
\end{cases}

Comment: Technically correct, but it doesn't actually help :) You've used d = rθ to express the equations without mentioning the letter r, but in practice those equations still involve calculating r in all but name (ie, they both involve d/θ) which means the problem with θ=0 or θ being very small remains. It is interesting that sinθ/θ tends to 1 and (cosθ-1)/θ tends to zero though :)

Comment: My point was only to have a formula involving only the distance and the angle.

Comment: Right - which would be fine if I were answering a math problem on paper. But I'm writing a computer program, and your equations still involve "d/θ", which is inaccurate or non-computable as θ approaches zero. The equations aren't using the LETTER r, but they are using the VALUE of r (i.e. d/θ) which is the problematic part :)

Comment: My *final* formuæ involve only $d$ and $\theta$, not $r$, which is used only for their justification. Your question says these data are given. And as far as I know, there are programs which can determine a limit with a good approximation.

Comment: I can't verify if this is useful here, but sometimes you can do a little bit better by computing the natural log of a quantity. So, you could compute $\ln{x} = \ln{d}+\ln{\sin{\theta}}-\ln{\theta}$. Which can be better as long as all three terms are not very close to one another. If they are, the subtraction will cause you to lose precision through cancellation.

Comment: You may also just be able to use a small angle approximation. If $\theta$ is small then $\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} \approx 1$ within an error of $\frac{\theta^2}{6}$. So if $\theta$ is prohibitively small then $\theta^2$ is minuscule.